# angular2 not applying bootstrap class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, material-design, angular

I am  have to bootstrap my angular2 component its not applying any bootstrap styling to html

here is my component login.ts

```
///<reference path="../../../node_modules/angular2/typings/node/node.d.ts" />

import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {FormBuilder,  FORM_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'login',    
})
@View({
  templateUrl: '/scripts/src/components/login/login.html',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class login {

}
```

here is my login template :

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" ng-class="panel-heading">
            <h4>Login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>User Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter username"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Please enter password"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer text-left">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

export class login {

}
```

here is my bootstrap.ts

```
//import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/node/node.d.ts" />
import {UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/upgrade';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {login} from './components/login/login';

bootstrap(login);
```

here  is my index.html

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>

    <script src="/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular2/bundles/upgrade.dev.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <login>Loading......</login>
    </div>
    <script>
       System.config({
            defaultJSExtensions: true,
        packages: {        
          app: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        },
        paths: {
            'angular2/upgrade': '../node_modules/angular2/upgrade'
          }

      });
        System.import('scripts/src/bootstrap');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

but when i run my app it give me output as

[image]

please help to style my app.

**what changes i need to do if i have to use material design**

Comment: You have commented your bootstrap css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Eric said you had the bootstrap styles commented out, and after your edit you don't even have them at all anymore.

Don't get confused with the bootstrap.js you are calling with systemjs, that's the angular's bootstrap method that wraps up your application dependencies and configuration in order to start it.

Just add the required bootstrap files like any other web app you'd make.

1-Core styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

2- Default theme if you want it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

3- If you are using Bootstrap JS components and not only styles:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

Just add those links inside the `head` tag of your index.html.

Comment: then bootstrap(login); what it does for me

Comment: Like I said: "wraps up your application dependencies and configuration in order to start it". if you read the Angular 2 quickstart you'll see they call it boot.js not bootstrap.js, it has nothing to do with the bootstrap framework, you can name it w/e you want.

Comment: What i have to do if i want to use Material design

Comment: The Material Design implementación for Angular 2 is far from done, you can use a bootstrap template that looks similar, MDL which is a material Design light CSS framework, or materialize, and see how good or bad they integrate with Angular 2

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to download the bootstrap from getBootstrap.com and add the bootstrap folder to your project, because if there is slow internet connection then there are possibilities that cdn's dont work and your theme might not look as per requirement.

You can download it from here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/